# Apigility how to make images available via public folder

Tags: laminas-api-tools

I'm currently creating a mobile app with Apigility as the API. All is working well and life is heaven on my laptop. However, when releasing onto OpenShift we can't access images under the public folder.

I'm calling the images with the full URL "http://coolapp.com/public/images/smile.jpg" but keep on getting access denied despite changing permissions on the DIR. Once again on my mac all works fine.

Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out version 1.0 of apigility has an issue completing update write under mac with an SSD drive. We moved project to a linux box did a manual composer update and voila! all is ok now.